# Dependency problems when upgrading from Debian 11 to Debian 12

Tags: debian

I am trying to upgrade my system from Debian 11 to Debian 12. When I run sudo apt full-upgrade,

```
λ ~/ main* sudo apt full-upgrade                                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libboost-thread1.74.0 : Breaks: libboost-regex1.74.0-icu67
libc6-dev : Breaks: libnetcdf-dev (<= 1:4.9.0-3) but 1:4.7.4-1 is to be installed
libgirepository-1.0-1 : Breaks: libgjs0g (< 1.68.4-1+b1) but 1.66.2-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I am afraid that I will break my system if I attempt to solve it alone. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix the dependency issue?

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 11.3.0 standard 2022-03-26T17:04]/ bullseye main

#deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 11.3.0 standard 2022-03-26T17:04]/ bullseye main

deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/debian/ bookworm main non-free contrib #non-free-firmware
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/debian/ bookworm main non-free contrib #non-free-firmware
 
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/debian-security/ bookworm-security main non-free contrib #non-free-firmware
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/debian-security/ bookworm-security main non-free contrib #non-free-firmware

deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/debian/ bookworm-updates main #non-free-firmware
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/debian/ bookworm-updates main #non-free-firmware

#deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye contrib non-free

deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/debian/ bookworm-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/debian/ bookworm-backports main contrib non-free
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list

```
λ ~/ main* sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

The output of apt list '?narrow(?installed, ?not(?origin(Debian)))' is 2239 lines long :(

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11D21kCt_2vy3MsaTU-gA5JEj2U5iNRoZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Some of the versions indicated in the error messages suggest you've mixed in packages from other distributions (maybe Ubuntu or PopOS) into your Debian installation. In other words, [you've made a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian). Please show the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files, so that we can evaluate how bad this case of FrankenDebian actually is. Also, please show the output of `apt list '?narrow(?installed, ?not(?origin(Debian)))'`.

Comment: Looks like the output is 2239 lines long...

Comment: Before even attempting to upgrade to Debian 11, please be sure it has first been upgraded to Debian 11.8 (not 11.7 or before). That would be the probable cause of so many "non-Debian" packages: not referenced anymore. (even if some of them such as chrome really are not Debian).

Comment: Try removing the file with google chrome. During the update it will create a new one, but possibly without breaking the system. Or maybe you installed other packages (maybe download + dpkg). Personally I use a lot `aptitude` which gives me more information, and I can select different solution (and I can change action for every package)

Comment: Unfortunately the `apt list ...` output would have been more useful before you changed the `sources.list` files to point to Debian 12. But you could temporarily remove any conflicting `*-dev` package, since removing them will not stop any existing binaries from working; only rebuilding some software projects from source might fail without them. But after the update is done, you would have to re-assess the dependencies of any software projects you need to build anyway...